# Issue while using a non-deterministic function in create mask return case statement

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to create an IBMi DB2 mask over a table as below:

```
CREATE or replace MASK IESWEBSERP.MASK_PWD_WSCONTROL ON IESWEBSERP.WSCONTROL
    FOR COLUMN WSVNDPWD    RETURN                                         
    CASE   
        WHEN (  VERIFY_GROUP_FOR_USER(SESSION_USER, 'ICC', 'IICCGRP')=1)
            THEN WSVNDPWD                                                              
        WHEN (  SESSION_USER  in ('QSQSRVR', 'QTMHHTTP', 'PROFOUNDJS', 'IESWEBSVR'))                  
            THEN WSVNDPWD  
        WHEN            IESWEBSERP.IES_CHECK_AUTH( WSDTALIB )  = 1        
            THEN WSVNDPWD
        WHEN     (WSVNDID  = IESWEBSERP.web_login_id )         
            THEN WSVNDPWD 

        ELSE    'MASKED'
    END                                                                 
ENABLE ;
```

The problem is with the **IESWEBSERP.IES_CHECK_AUTH** user defined function used in the RETURN CASE.

As per the documentation, I understand that the RETURN CASE statement cannot use a Non-Deterministic function. So below is how this udf is defined:

```
Create or REPLACE Function IESWEBSERP.IES_CHECK_AUTH(                                
            DATA_LIBRARY CHAR(10))                                             
     returns dec(1,0)                                                
     language SQL
     NO EXTERNAL ACTION
     DETERMINISTIC
     NOT FENCED
     SECURED                                                     
  BEGIN

    declare q char(1) ;
    declare back char(1) ;
    declare @sqlStmt1 varchar(500) ;
    declare @sqlStmt varchar(500) ;
    declare myCursor cursor for myStatement;
    declare myCursor1 cursor for myStatement1;
    set q = '''';
    set @sqlStmt1 =  'select count(*) from QSYS2.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ' 
                    concat q concat TRIM(DATA_LIBRARY) concat q  
                    concat ' and TABLE_NAME = ' concat q concat 'MSTCONTL' concat q;
    prepare myStatement1  from @SqlStmt1;                    
    open myCursor1;
    Fetch myCursor1 into back;
    close myCursor1;
    IF ( back = '1' )
        THEN 
            SET back = '0' ;
            set @sqlStmt =  'select count(*) from ' concat TRIM(DATA_LIBRARY) concat '.MSTCONTL 
            where USRID = SESSION_USER and (USRC2 =' concat q concat 'U' concat q 
            concat 'or USRC2 = ' concat q concat 'P' concat q concat')'; 

            prepare myStatement  from @SqlStmt;
            open myCursor;
            Fetch myCursor into back;
            close myCursor;
            IF ( back = '1' )
              THEN SET back = '1' ;
            ELSE SET back = '0' ;
               

            END IF ;
 
       ELSE SET back = '0' ;
    END IF ;

    return(back );
END;
```

All the UDF does is it checks if value of field MSTCONTL.USRC2 is 'U' or 'P' for the user record of the current session user. If it is so, it returns a value of '1' which would allow the user to see the value of the field WSVNDPWD without any masking.

But the catch is that if the value MSTCONTL.USRC2 is updated to a value other than U or P, the function would still return '1' (if '1' was returned earlier as well).. This I believe is because the function is defined as DETERMINISTIC.

If I make the function non DETERMINSTIC, the create mask statement fails. So I am not sure how to handle this situation. I want a "dynamic" result from the function. Please can someone advise how this can be handled?

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of determinism for SQL statements: global and statement.  By using the `deterministic` keyword above, you are making the function globally deterministic which means it expects EVERY call with the same parameters to always return the same result as the very first time its called.

You can change this to `statement deterministic` instead and I suspect this will do what you want.  Statement deterministic means that this call will return the same result every time its using in this particular statement call but it might change the next time this statement is called.  That means it does a new fresh lookup to cache the value every time this statement is used and reuses that value until this particular call is complete.

The biggest difference between statement deterministic and non-deterministic is that if someone changes the column value for this in a non-deterministic function, it could in theory change the masking halfway through processing a result.  Statement deterministic will not allow this but it does allow changing the masking results between two separate runs of the statement.

Note that the documentation here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-create-mask#fntarg_1 does say that statement deterministic is not recommended in SQL mask procedures but it does not give a reason why.  I suspect it is for performance reasons so you will have to determine if the possible performance or other hit is worth it for your case.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!! You have won the bounty!!